# Python regex backreference to swap characters in a string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to swap h and w  in "hello World" as "wello horld" using back referencing. I am  able to capture the group but something goes wrong when I refer the group in sub() method.

```
import re
st = "hello world"
t = re.compile(r"(\w).+\s(\w).+")
res = t.sub(r"\2 \1",st)
print(res)
```

I get output as "w h" instead of the desired string. What am I missing ?

Comment: `r"\2 \1"`` is the *complete* string you want output... so you'll need to also capture the parts you're not swapping and output those...

Comment: So that is `t = re.compile(r"(\w)(.+\s)(\w)")` and replace with `r"\3\2\1"`

Answer (score 1):

Your regex approach has a problem.  You should capture, for each word, two groups, the first character and rest of the word.  Actually, we can just capture the first letter of the second word.

```py
st = "hello world"
output = re.sub(r'(\w)(\w*) (\w)', r'\3\2 \1', st)
print(output)  # wello horld
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not capturing the first match correctly. The following will work for you:

```
import re st = "hello world" t = re.compile(r"(?<=\w)\.(?=\w)") res = t.sub(r"\2 \1",st) print(res)
```

Explanation: (?<=\w) is a positive look-behind assertion which ensures that we have at least one word character before us while matching any char but a whitespace or end of line, and similarly (?=\w) is a positive look-ahead assertion which makes sure that there's a word char after our current position. Also note how . matches both a literal dot as well as a special regex metacharacter. Hope it helps!

Comment: Why is all the code in the same line?

Comment: There is no dot in `hello world`, why are you matching a dot?